# Prescribed intersection of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, intersection-theory, complete-intersection

Every variety here is complex analytic, or complex algebraic if it solves anything.

Given a *germ* of a (possibly singular, nor necessarily irreducible) hypersurface $(H,0)\subset(\mathbb{C}^{n+1},0)$ and an irreducible curve $(C,0)\subset(H,0)$, does a **surface** $(S,0)$ such that $H\cap S=C$ (set-theoretically, as germs) always exist? Are there general conditions that give this (such as $C$ being complete intersection)?

I do not care much about the structure of the varieties, except for the dimension.

Comment: No that does not always exist.  Consider the germ at the vertex of a cone over a smooth plane cubic, and let the curve be the line through the vertex corresponding to a nontorsion point on the plane cubic (use one of the flex points as the origin).

Comment: @JasonStarr could you elaborate a bit more on why there is no surface $S$ as asked? Thanks.